# Flex AS3 - Creating a dynamic property, and then binding a control to it

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I am trying to:
1) create a dynamic property
2) bind that property to a label

This works great for "sealed properties", but for dynamic properties there doesn't appear to be any event triggered.  Are dynamic properties ***implicityly not*** bindable?

```
var myObj:MyType = new MyType(); // MyType is dynamic
myObj["myDynamicPropertyName"] = "initialized";

BindingUtils.bindProperty(myLabel, "data", myObj, repeatedLabel.name); // myLabel now displays "initialized"

myObj["myDynamicPropertyName"] = "changed";  // myLabel still displays "initialized", it should say "changed" !!!
```

Comment: Does the compiler give you any warnings? It does at least for certain things (like binding to the length of an array, for example).

Answer (score 1):

mwilson: No compiler warnings

Cory Petosky: I tried that earlier, the method is called first time I set the dynamic property, but not the second.

Comment: Ok thanks Cory, I'll try that out today and post back with my results.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Try BindingUtils.bindProperty(myLabel, "data", myObj, {  name: repeatedLabel.name, getter: function(host) { return host[repeatedLabel.name]; } });</del>

Dynamic properties don't appear in `describeType`, so apparently the system can't bind to them.

If your type doesn't already extend something, you could extend `Proxy` and override the `setProperty` function to dispatch data change events. If it does already extend something... you'll have to figure out another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your object into an [mx.utils.ObjectProxy](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/utils/ObjectProxy.html) and then use this wrapper to place your listeners. However, you also should use this wrapper, instead of the original object, to update the values of those properties, in order for the correct binding events to be fired.